# error on delphi loading, after install UniDac componnent

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, unidac

i download UniDac component for delphi XE2 and installed it, now when run DelphiXE2 file i get bellow errors from delphi and when press ok, delphi load successfully but the UniDac component not installed.

### The errors listed include:

### bds.exe - System Error

### The program can't start because fmx162.bpl is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

### OK

[Window Title]
Error

[Content]
Could not find Wizard, 'd:\Program Files\Devart\UniDAC for RAD Studio XE2\Bin\Win32\unimigwizard160.dll'.

[OK]

---

### bds.exe - System Error

### The program can't start because fmx162.bpl is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

### OK

and finally get this error:

[Window Title]
Error

[Content]
Can't load package d:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\9.0\bin\dclunidac160.bpl.
The specified module could not be found.
Do you want to attempt to load this package the next time a project is loaded?

[Yes] [No]

thanks.

Comment: You must have XE2 update 4 installed.

Comment: Ok, I made an answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi XE2 is coming in various updates, mainly because of the fresh FireMonkey features.

Unfortunately these updates have to break the bpl format. XE2 update 4 (the latest) are using fmx162.bpl, so you will have to install this update in order to use the latest unidac components.